# What PDO query should i use?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table on my database which called topics(topic_id,topic_subject,topic_content,topic_date,topic_cat,topic_comm,topic_by,votes,tags,views,flags), from this table i want to echo
10 top users(topic_by) with the most topics(max number of topics) on a specific community(topic_comm). What PDO query should i use ? I think need something like below:

```
$sql = $conn -> prepare("SELECT topic_by WHERE topic_comm=:comm AND ( MAX COUNT(topic_id) )")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let construct the query step by step. In order to get the top 10 user by most topic by community, you need to compute number of topic by each user on that community.

```
SELECT topic_by, COUNT(*) AS total_topic FROM topic 
WHERE topic_comm = :comm GROUP BY topic_by
```

Then, you want to get the top 10 user, you can use  basic subquery and `LIMIT`. So the final query

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT topic_by, COUNT(*) AS total_topic FROM topic 
  WHERE topic_comm = :comm GROUP BY topic_by
) AS t ORDER BY t.total_topic DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I like your step by step explanation. +1